# How to modify angular for hashbang url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to add a #! to the route instead of #. (/#/ --> /#!/). However, I am getting an error when I try to modify $location: (Unknown provider: $location from myApp)

app.js file

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeController'});
        $routeProvider.when('/results', {templateUrl: 'partials/results.html', controller: 'ResultsController'});
        $routeProvider.when('/print/:param1', {templateUrl: 'partials/print.html', controller: 'PrintController'});
        $routeProvider.when('/results/:param1', {templateUrl: 'partials/results.html', controller: 'ResultsController'});

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
  }]);

//enable hashbang (#!) url for google SEO
myApp.config(['$location', function($location) {
        $location.hashPrefix('!');
    }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the provider(`$locationProvider`) to configure the service(`$location`)..

```
myApp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Comment: @WilliamFalcon  It gets easier, and it will be worth it.